# mysql INNER JOIN displaying incorrect information

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I am running into an issue when trying to perform an inner join on 2 tables
here are the tables

```
addressBookUsers[
userid int PK Auto increment
username VARCHAR
password VARCHAR
]

addressbook[
aid int PK Auto Increment 
address VAR CHAR
uId int FK REFRENCE(userid) FROM addressBookUsers
]
```

here is some example data

```
addressBookUsers
userid   username  password  
1        fred      21434234 
2        al        3243254 
3        web       fdsafdr


addressbook
aid   address  uId
1     2314     1
2     ererw    1
3     edfwrf   2
4     dfadf    2
```

this is the query i am running. When I run it the all of the data gets printed into the table rather than just the data for the specific user

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addressbook INNER JOIN addressBookUsers ON addressbook.uId = addressBookUsers.userid ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `UserID`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addressbook INNER JOIN addressBookUsers ON addressbook.uId = addressBookUsers.userid  and addressbook.uId=". $UserID. ";)
```

OR

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addressbook INNER JOIN addressBookUsers ON addressbook.uId = addressBookUsers.userid  where addressbook.uId=". $UserID. ";)
```

EDIT:

Because Inner join Gives only ON Set of Column you specified. So it will gives All matching 
Rows belongs to `addressBookUsers.userid` for `addressbook.uid` so again You need to Filter by where Clause or using join

Comment: why would i need to specify it? shouldnt it get the value automatically just from addressbook.uId and addressBookUsers.userid? Thanks

Comment: @onebadbaggins your welcome you thing this is helpful then mark it as answer on left side tick